# How to store values inside a 2D array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I use this sql to get the language and v=level of language. I have checked the sql in phpmyadmin and it is correct.

```
$qry3 = "Select Language, Level 
            from languages l, particulars_language pl 
            where pl.Particulars_ID = ". $ID ." 
            and l.Language_ID = pl.Language_ID;";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $qry3);
```

Below i would like to add in data of their language and level of language from the database. How do you do it?

```
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
        {
            $Language = $row1['Language'];
            $Level = $row1['Level'];
            $languagelevel = array
            (
                array($Language,$Level)
            );

        }

        ?>
```

Comment: What's your desired output? `array('en' => 9, 'cn' => 3,...)`? `array(array('en',9), array('cn', 3))`? Just to give some examples of possible output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update these code with these one

```
$languagelevel = array();
 while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
        {
            $Language = $row1['Language'];
            $Level = $row1['Level'];
            $languagelevel[] = array
            (
               $Language,$Level
            );

        }

        ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Make language as `KEY` and level as `VALUE`.

```
$languagelevel[$Language] = $Level;
```

Read how PHP associative array works from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

Comment: what do you mean language as key and level and value? Sorry i dont really get it. Yes i did went to that website to learn about array but i realised they use foreach to add in array and for my case i cant do foreach because it is from sql. So i feel my code will overwrite the prev data stored in the array.

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

First let the while loop make two 1-D arrays. Declare your 2-D array outside this loop.

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        //Make 1-D arrays
    }
$languagelevel = array
        (
            array($Language,$Level)
        );
```